# Cannot run program "script.sh" (in directory "/app/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/nirmalya/appcache/application) error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

I have configured hdfs path where my workflow.xml & script.sh file is present.

In Hadoop cluster web UI, I can see job status showing as SUCCEEDED.

But in OOZIE Web console, this error message is showing.

Since, it is failing i am unable to find the path /app/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/nirmalya/appcache/application_1706529891714_0002/container_1706529891714_0002_01_000002

I can see the path upto /app/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/nirmalya/appcache/

And one more thing I have noticed in /app/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/filecache/ path - some folders (10, 11, 12/lib_20240118131542, 13, 14) created.

And inside of these folders - oozie-hadoop-utils-1.1.1.oozie-4.1.0.jar , oozie-sharelib-oozie-4.1.0.jar, sharelib.properties, script.sh, json-simple-1.1.jar these files are locked respectively.

I have also checked the read and write, create and delete permission is given for this path /app/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/filecache/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foKIH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdT6d.png)

One more error is showing hadoop job logs - org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebAppException: /localhost:8088/jobhistory/logs/nirmalya-Lenovo-V15-G2-ITL-Ua:37221/container_1706661377640_0002_01_000001/container_1706661377640_0002_01_000001/nirmalya: controller for localhost:8088 not found
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Router.resolveDefault(Router.java:232)

How can I solve this error ?? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

My workflow.xml -

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="my_workflow">
    <start to="abc"/>
      <action name='abc'>
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
          <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
          <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
          <exec>script.sh</exec>
          <file>/user/nirmalya/share/lib/script.sh#script.sh</file>
        </shell>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
      </action>
      <kill name="fail">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
      </kill>
      <end name="end"/> 
    </workflow-app>
```

My job.properties -

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000
jobTracker=localhost:8050
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath=hdfs://localhost:9000/user/nirmalya/share/lib
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/nirmalya/oozie_workflows/
```

My expectation is to run the script.sh file successfully in oozie job status.

My script.sh -

#!/bin/bash
whoami
date